# Do Windows Forms Controls run without the form?

Tags: .net, winforms

1. Can I use some features of a control without rendering it?
2. Can I use some features of a control in a console app?

NB: I tried to use a hidden WebBrowser control, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I answered this in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525282/how-to-use-an-invisible-system-windows-forms-webbrowser/3525669#3525781), controls like WebBrowser need a message loop.  There is no message loop in a console app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create an instance of a control without adding it to a form.

If you have a question about specific functionality, you'll need to ask it specifically.