# Script error while loading url in web browser control?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

```
<fieldset><b>&nbsp;</b><button id="submit" class="googleCheckPosButt" 
onclick="docSubmit()">CHECK</button></fieldset>
</form>
```

This is a source code of a webpage where I am trying to put data into a form and submit it.  I can successfully enter data into the text fields of the page, but when the web page loads in a web browser it shows a script error and when I click on any of the buttons on the page, nothing works.  I have hidden the error messages by adding:

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

theElementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection)
{
    if (curElement.GetAttribute("id").Equals("submit"))
    {
        curElement.InvokeMember("click");                       
    }
}
```

Please Help me how can i enter data into the site with out getting script error messages

Comment: What is the script error you are receiving?

Comment: it doesn't matter. he wants to disable any and all errors.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use a browser control to do this type of automated form submission, I would instead recommend using something like http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com along with the example from [HtmlAgilityPack Post Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532266/htmlagilitypack-post-login) to work it.

Comment: but HTMLAgilityPack cannot be used to enter data in textboxes and click buttons? Am i right?