# How login into shopping web site using web client

Tags: c#, .net, screen-scraping, web-crawler, web-scraping

I have a requirement to login into shopping website through code. I am will be using Webclient for that.

I am not finding a start point on how to do it? Can some share a code sample on how i can do that with any shopping web site or share some resource books , blogs etc

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: it will be great if I can see an example. Lets say i have login into walmart.

Comment: See this SO answer.  I used it to successfully log into a site and then scrape with HTML Agility Pack... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471893/using-browsersession-and-htmlagilitypack-to-login-to-facebook-through-net