# How can I Browse a page Programmatically?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I've seen numerous examples on how to get the contents of a URI. I also used HTMLAgilityPack a lot.
What I want is to create Unit Testing environment for asp websites.

I've seen the [BrowserSession](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-and-post.html) and this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471893/using-browsersession-and-htmlagilitypack-to-login-to-facebook-through-net) but although, the process seems fine, they do not login in a website. I tried numerous well-known websites.

Any ideas on how to browse though code?

Comment: Are you asking about the rendered HTML that you would see using the View Source feature of most browsers? Or are you asking about browsing the ASP code on the server?

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for something like this: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

Comment: @jsmarble About the rendered page.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to submit a form on a web page and view the response HTML back of the resulting page.

This method will take a form target URL and submit a post with the given named arguments in the parms Dictionary.

I have used the method below to perform password authentication on a web page and view the response after authentication. You will need to know the target Url and the form fields you wish to pass in the request.

```
private string SubmitRequest(string url, Dictionary<string, string> parms)
{
    var req = WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Method = "POST";

    string parmsString = string.Join("&", parms.Select(p => string.Format("{0}={1}", p.Key, p.Value)));
    req.ContentLength = parmsString.Length;

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        writer.Write(parmsString);
        writer.Close();
    }

    var res = req.GetResponse();

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        return response;
    }
}
```

If there is something more specific you are wanting or this is not what you are looking for then please post a comment.

Comment: I want to be able to login to a website, and browse it. This requires coockies, hidden input fields etc.

Comment: As far as I know the method above would let you login to a website and read the output because you can pass whatever form fields you'd like to the POST. Now for browsing around the site after that I'd think you're to the point of needing an actual web browser. Your original question did not mention cookies, so I'm not sure how far this will get you, but it should at least get you to the post-login landing page.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to try some tutorials of WebDriverJs and see if that works for you. It is mainly used for testing but can also be used for other purposes. I am using it to automate responding to user's queries on a shopping platform.