# missing cookie in post request

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to log in on site https://logowanie.play.pl/p4-idp2/LoginForm.do.
To achieve that, I'm using [htmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and [BrowserSession by Rohit Agarwal](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-and-post.html).

To look how loging on this web look, I chosed [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

when i'm loging by browser, there is part: 
[image: Post request from web browser]

But when i'm trying to do the same by code, it's look like:
[image: Post request from code]

I think that problem is with missing Cookie in second case. But when i'm debugging code, Cookie with sessionid IS including into request:
[image: debug session]

I relay cant understand, why cookie is not included with request. Someone can help me?

Here is my code:

```
    BrowserSession session = new BrowserSession();
    Random rrr = new Random();
    session.Get(@"http://24.play.pl/");

    session.Post(@"https://logowanie.play.pl/p4-idp2/SSOrequest.do?action=sso");
    session.FormElements["login"] = "[censored]";
    session.FormElements["password"] = "[also censored]";
    string url = @"https://logowanie.play.pl/p4-idp2/Login.do";
    string response = session.Post(url);

    textBox1.Text = response;
```

rest of used code is on [Rohit Agarwal blog](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-and-post.html)

Comment: Same problem, hopefully this gets an answer

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, but I solved it by slightly modifying the [BrowserSession](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.de/2010/04/using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-and-post.html) class.

Have a look at my solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11286183/1424439). Maybe it helps you too.